# SXA Search Results Grouping

Tags: sxa, solr, content-search

I am using `Sitecore 9.0` with `SXA 1.6` and `Solr` search provider. Is there a way to display results grouped in SXA Search results components?

Comment: Could you be more precise? I am not sure what is your goal. Some example would be helpful.

Comment: I need to know if SXA search results components supports grouping the search results using specific field as per the below URL : https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/using_solr_to_group_search_results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SXA is not supporting this feature out of the box. To be able to use that feature you would need to:

- enable this feature on your Solr server
- modify SXA SearchService to perform a custom query and then group results as shown in the document from the link you paste - I strongly recommend not to do that

If you still want to use this grouping feature then the best option for you would be to write a custom rendering.